# EXEC sp_readerrorlog date Parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, parameters

I would like to execute the following statement using a date parameter.

```
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 6 -- specify the log number or use nothing for active error log
```

The parameter should be able to pull only the **current date**, for example **NOW()** or **TODAY()**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `sp_readerrorlog` internally uses `sys.xp_readerrorlog`, which can take optional from-and-to dates like so:

```
declare @start date=GetDate(), @end date=DateAdd(day,1,GetDate())

exec sys.xp_readerrorlog 1, 1, null, null, @start, @end, N'asc'
```